# Como criar uma função para passar um JSON no django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Eu estou estudando drf e gostaria de criar uma função que recebesse uma lista no formato JSON e fizesse um update pelo serializer.

Para exemplificar melhor segue como estou pensando.

example_serializer.py

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    model = Car
```

Estou pensando algo, mais ou menos, assim:

exemplo_view.py

```
class GarageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Garage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GarageSerializer
    model = Garage

        @action(methods=['put'], detail=False)
        def update_car(self, request, *args, **kwargs):     
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = CarSerializer(data=data, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Quando tento passar, através da API, os dados a serem atualziados eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
{
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Necessário uma lista de itens, mas recebeu tipo \"dict\"."
    ]
}
```

Algum norte que possa me ajudar?

Comment: Vc apresenta 2 serializers? e somente uma view?, qual é a sua duvida especificamente? vc ja tentou implmentar o que esta pensando? qual foi o resultado? algum erro?

Comment: e ae @Sidon. Blz? Obrigado pela reposta. O número de serializers e views foi apenas para exemplificar o que quero. No mais, coloquei mais dados, inclusive, uma nova tentativa e o erro. Abraços

Comment: Ok, mas onde estão os designs/definições dos serializers?